# Why is a second local player with an XBOX Live Silver account allowed to play online?

Tags: xbox-360, dungeon-defenders

This is typically not allowed on XBL, but I noticed Dungeon Defenders somehow got around this. I can't find any information online as to whether this was done as a promotion or some agreement between Microsoft and Trendy Entertainment.

I'm not talking about the second player playing as a guest under the first player's profile.

Comment: I should note that my account is the first player account and is XBL Gold

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the "this is not typically allowed" bit - the Halo series has always allowed guests to play alongside a main play with XBL Gold, as has Call of Duty and numerous other series.

Comment: I think this is the case when they are playing as a guest under your profile. But hasn't it always been the case that if the second player wants to use their own profile that they have to have XBL gold?

Comment: Carrying on with my research. No luck yet. I have been able to replicate this using my XBL Gold and friend's XBL Silver account several times. We can get in to an online match no problem. He gets to use his personal characters, bank mana, etc.

I'm not saying this is a bad thing, I just want to know if there are other such games so I can collect them.

Comment: Gotcha - was unaware that actual usage of a secondary profile and items local to that profile was possible. However, I don't think this question is a good fit - a list of games that let you do this wouldn't be appropriate, and the question "Why did the devs let local profiles play online" isn't really answerable. I'd recommend asking about this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35).

Comment: @IanPugsley While in the comments it is mentioned that if this is the way things are a list of games that are also like it are the end goal, the overall question of this being something unique to Dungeon Defenders or not still seems valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

The account type of the second account does not matter, and that is global across all games.

It only takes into account the person who is running the game, so to speak. The second local person could be using a gold, silver or even just a guest account and would still be able to enjoy the online matching brought about by the gold account.. They are just there for the ride, nothing more.

Comment: I think this is the case when they are playing as a guest under your profile. But hasn't it always been the case that if the second player wants to use their own profile that they have to have XBL gold?

Comment: I have never had that come up as a concern before in the years of playing XBL games.. As long as one account has the game unlocked with a gold account, the other accounts piggy back on that one.

Comment: Actually, COD MW2 doesn't allow this.